# How can I format the response coming from the server as given below using js array methods such as map(), reduce(), filter() and etc?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the response object from an API that I need to reformat:

```
const data = {
  id: 12,
  currency: "USD",
  transactions: [
    {
      from_wallet_id: 14,
      transaction_amount: '30.00',
      type: 'income',
      "date": "2019-12-04T06:45:49.394000+06:00"
    },
    {
      from_wallet_id: 11,
      transaction_amount: '50.00',
      type: 'expenses',
      date: "2019-12-04T06:45:49.394000+06:00"
    },
    {
      from_wallet_id: 11,
      transaction_amount: '70.00',
      type: 'transfer',
      date: "2019-12-06T06:45:49.394000+06:00"
    },
    {
      from_wallet_id: 14,
      transaction_amount: '40.00',
      type: 'transfer',
      date: "2019-12-08T06:45:49.394000+06:00"
    },
  ]
}
```

I need to change it to the example given below (using array methods such as reduce, map, filter, etc)
A little bit information:
income is sum of transactions at that date.
expenses is sum of transactions at that date.
type "transfer" can be income or expense
If type is "transfer" and from_wallet_id is not equals to data.id
then it will be added to income otherwise it will be added to expenses

```
formattedObject = {
  "2019-12-04": {
    date: "2019-12-04",
    income: 30,
    expenses: 50
  },
  "2019-12-06": {
    date: "2019-12-06",
    income: 0,
    expenses: 70
  },
  "2019-12-08": {
    date: "2019-12-08",
    income: 40,
    expenses: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the array nad take an adjustment for `type: 'transfer'`.

```js
const
    data = { id: 12, currency: "USD", transactions: [{ from_wallet_id: 14, transaction_amount: '30.00', type: 'income', date: "2019-12-04T06:45:49.394000+06:00" }, { from_wallet_id: 11, transaction_amount: '50.00', type: 'expenses', date: "2019-12-04T06:45:49.394000+06:00" }, { from_wallet_id: 11, transaction_amount: '70.00', type: 'transfer', date: "2019-12-06T06:45:49.394000+06:00" }, { from_wallet_id: 14, transaction_amount: '40.00', type: 'transfer', date: "2019-12-08T06:45:49.394000+06:00" }] },
    result = data.transactions.reduce((r, { from_wallet_id, transaction_amount, type, date }) => {
        date = date.slice(0, 10);
        if (type === 'transfer') type = data.id === from_wallet_id ? 'expenses' : 'income'; 
        r[date] = r[date] || { date, income: 0, expenses: 0 };
        r[date][type] += +transaction_amount;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```